# Liberty profile not injecting ejb in servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, websphere-liberty

I googled without luck trying to understand why Liberty Profile 8.5.5.6 does not inject EJB into a servlet

I put everything into a war. The war deployed fine, but when I call the servlet I get the following error:

```
Exception thrown by application class 'org.javaee7.servlet.simple.UserServlet.doGet:23'
java.lang.NullPointerException:
at org.javaee7.servlet.simple.UserServlet.doGet(UserServlet.java:23)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
at [internal classes]
```

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317544/injecting-ejb-into-servlet) link I saw a comment that I should use @ManagedBean

When I try this, the null pointer exception goes away but now I get this error:

```
Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0319E: For the [UserServlet] servlet, org.javaee7.servlet.simple.UserServlet servlet class was found, but a resource injection failure has occurred. CWNEN0030E: The server was unable to obtain an object instance for the java:comp/env/org.javaee7.servlet.simple.UserServlet/service reference. The exception message was: The EJB reference in the lps.war module of the lps application could not be resolved; nested exception is: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBNotFoundException: EJB with interface org.javaee7.service.UserService not present in application lps.
```

Here is my code:

```
@Stateless
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    public User getUser(Long id) {
        return new User(id, "Gary");
    }
}

@Remote
public interface UserService {
    public User getUser(Long id);
}

@ManagedBean
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB(mappedName = "UserServiceImpl")
    UserService service;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        User user = service.getUser(1L);
        response.getWriter().print(user == null ? "no user" : user.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - for sure you shouldn't use `@ManagedBean`. Servlet is not a managed bean. You dont need that for injection to work.
You should have either `@WebServlet` in your servlet or configure it via `web.xml`.
Second - you should remove `mappedName` as Liberty is not using that.

Please add `server.xml` to your question as you may be lacking some features.
You should have either `ejbRemote-3.2` or `javaee-7.0` feature there among others.

For remote interfaces you have to use the following binding:

```
@EJB(lookup="java:global/AppName/ModuleName/UserServiceImpl!org.javaee7.service.UserService")
private UserService service;
```

You can also use other bindings like below depending on your config:

```
java:global/ExampleApp/ExampleModule/ExampleBean!com.ibm.example.ExampleRemoteInterface    
java:app/ExampleModule/ExampleBean!com.ibm.example.ExampleRemoteInterface    
java:module/ExampleBean!com.ibm.example.ExampleRemoteInterface
```

When your bean is binding you should see the following message in the log:

```
[INFO    ] CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.ibm.example.ExampleRemoteInterface interface of the ExampleRemote enterprise bean in the Example.war module of the Example application.  
The binding location is: java:global/Example/ExampleRemote!com.ibm.example.ExampleRemoteInterface
```

UPDATE
In case of same app just `@EJB` without any lookup works for me also.

See also for more details:

- Chapter 5.2.3 Developing applications using remote EJB in [WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile Guide for Developers Redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpieces/abstracts/sg248076.html)
- Infocenter [Using enterprise JavaBeans with remote interfaces on the Liberty profile](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.iseries.doc/ae/twlp_ejb_remote.html?lang=en)

Comment: What would the AppName and ModuleName be when I am deploying a war file called lps.war

Comment: @javapenguin In case of just one war it should be just the module name so  `java:global/lps/UserServiceImpl!org.javaee7.service.UserService`

Comment: As soon as I removed web.xml it worked. Looks like if you use annotations (@WebServlet) you should stick to them.